# SWFUpload - How to Cancel Queued Files

Tags: swfupload

I'm a little confused on how to cancel an upload in SWFUpload. I know you have to pass the cancelUpload() function the ID of the upload, but it seems like when I do this it doesn't work. A sample of my code would be:

```
function remove(number, id) {
    cancelUpload(id);
}

<span onClick = "remove(0, 'SWFUpload_0_0')">filename</span>
```

However, the file still uploads. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to add the variable you assign SWFUpload to. In this case, swfu.cancelUpload() worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is already in handlers.js file. This will cancel your current queued file.

```
ar progress = new FileProgress(file, this.customSettings.progressTarget);
progress.toggleCancel(true);
```